# Simple add function to a adjacency matrix

Tags: java

I'm developing an adjacency matrix so i can try and use a DFS to solve the euler circuit problem.
This is the relevant code to my question:

```
public class Graph {

private int numVertex;
private int numEdges;
private boolean[][] adj;

public Graph(int numVertex, int numEdges) {
    this.numVertex = numVertex;
    this.numEdges = numEdges;
    this.adj = new boolean[numVertex][numVertex];
}

public void addEdge(int start, int end){
    if(!adj[start][end])
        numEdges++;
    adj[start][end] = true;
    adj[end][start] = true;
}
```

When i try and test run this code by adding some edges i get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
at Graph.addEdge(Graph.java:18)
at Graph.main(Graph.java:66)
```

I'm using this to test the code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int numVertices = input.nextInt();
    int numLinks = input.nextInt();
    int startNode = input.nextInt();

    Graph g = new Graph(numVertices, numLinks);

    for(int i = 0; i<numLinks; i++){
        g.addEdge(input.nextInt(),input.nextInt());
    }
```

I think the problem is in the addEdge function. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that your matrix is zero-based.

If you passed 4 as numVertices, your matrix will go from 0,0 to 3,3.

Then if you try to add an edge between vertex 4 and any other you will have an error...

Answer (score 2):

When you increment the number of edges, the size of the `adj` matrix does not change automatically. When you grow the graph, you need to reallocate the matrix and copy the old values over to the new matrix. You can save on reallocations by allocating a larger matrix to start with (so there's a difference between size and capacity) and only reallocating when you run out of capacity.

May I suggest that, since you are just storing a boolean, instead of a two-dimensional matrix, you just use a `BitSet` (which is really a bit vector, not a set). You can convert (row, column) pairs to a linear array index using:

```
index = row * numEdges + column;
```

and you can go the other way (if necessary) with:

```
column = index % numEdges;
row = index / numEdges;
```

You still need to reallocate the `BitSet` when the graph grows, but you will save a whole lot of storage.

**EDIT**

On second thought, I think that the problem is that you are not checking that the vertex numbers are within range. If you want the user to specify vertex numbers starting at 1, you need to subtract 1 from the user input so that the indexing of `adj` starts at 0. At a minimum, you should check that the end point inputs are valid.

If you want to try it, a `BitSet` implementation would look something like this:

```
public class Graph {

private int numVertex;
private int numEdges;
private BitSet adj;

public Graph(int numVertex, int numEdges) {
    this.numVertex = numVertex;
    this.numEdges = numEdges;
    this.adj = new BitSet(numVertex * numVertex);
}

public void addEdge(int start, int end){
    int index = start * numVertex + end;
    if (!adj.get(index)) {
        adj.set(index);
        index = end * numVertex + start;
        adj.set(index);
        numEdges++;
    }
}
```

Since the adjacency matrix is symmetric, you could save more storage by only storing the upper (or lower) triangular part. But that would make the indexing calculation a bit more complicated.

Comment: Hi Ted, i didn't understand... You recommended me to change the implementation i have, or that's a possible correction to the implementation i have? How would it look like using Bit Set?

Comment: @CláudioRibeiro - I think I missed something in my first response. I've edited my answer and also provided some sample code for using `BitSet`.